# Customizing CentOS7.0 - partition size

Tags: centos, system-installation, kickstart

I use a kickstart file for a CentOS7.0 installation.

I would like to configure the size of the root partition `/` so that it takes all the space available on the drive `/dev/sda`. The default setting for `part` is only 9GB and it's too small for me. How can I use `part / --size` to use all the disk space of a drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `--grow` option, that will use all the remaining space on disk. Note that you still need to define a minimum size if you want to use the whole disk:

```
part / --size=1 --grow
```